# tree. Spacebar hotkey

Tags: java, listener, vaadin

I want to use spacebar hotkey to expand/collapse nodes. It works perfectly well for enter, and it doesn`t work for space (just select/deselect node). here is my code:

```
 final Action actionEnter = new ShortcutAction("Select node",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ENTER, null);
    final Action actionSpace = new ShortcutAction("Select node1",
            ShortcutAction.KeyCode.SPACEBAR, null);

    treePanel.addActionHandler(new Action.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleAction(Action action, Object sender, Object target) {
            if (action==actionEnter || action==actionSpace){
                Object curId = tree.getValue();
                expandCollapse(curId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Action[] getActions(Object target, Object sender) {
            return new Action[] { actionEnter, actionSpace };
        }
    });
```

What is the problem with space hotkey?

Comment: If you run this in the debugger does the handleAction code get hit when you press the spacebar?

Comment: no...it doesn`t. only when enter is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Add a `KeyListener` to the tree and then you can handle all of the events from there.

Comment: can you provide a small example ?